# How to use System.Text.RegularExpression Regex in a Visual Studio Database Project CLR

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sqlclr, database-project, sql-server-2017

I am trying to convert an old CLR into a Database Project in Visual Studio 2017 which uses System.Text.RegularExpressions.   There is a lot of RegEx in the project and I don't want to have to change it if I can help it.

NuGet is not available in a Database Project as I understand it and System.Text is not available as an assembly when I try to add it as a reference.

What is the easiest way to install System.Text.RegularExpressions into the database project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System.Text** is not an assembly, which is why it cannot be included. It is a namespace. The **System.Text.RegularExpressions** namespace is found in a few assemblies. Most of it can be found in the main **System.dll** assembly which should already be included as a reference. You can see this in the documentation for the [Match Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.7.1). You should not need to do anything besides making sure that the following line is at the top of the **.cs** file:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```